# How to generate warning for invalid insert conditions in psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, tkinter, psycopg2

I have a table myuser with two columns (id serial primary, username varchar(20) unique not null). I am trying to make a Tkinter gui that takes "username" from a form and inserts it in the postgres table myuser.

I want to generate a warning when "username" field is left empty (or any other invalid requests) in the gui. How to do that ? Could not find any suitable answers in psycopg error lists.

I tried the following, but if I keep the username field in the gui empty, I don't see any warning, and the program runs without error. I expected to see a warning with this if condition.

Also, if there are other types of invalidity (> 20 characters), my solution would not work. So, what would be the best way for doing this ?

```
name = namefield.get() 
try:
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO myuser (username)
        VALUES (%s)''', (name,)
        )
    if name == None:
       print('Please insert a valid username')
    
except psycopg2.IntegrityError:
   conn.rollback()
else:
   conn.commit()
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Make  the `username` field  NOT NULL and add CHECK constraint `length(trim(username)) > 0 and length(trim(username)) <= 20`. Then report the error in your `except`. This ensures you throw an error regardless of the client used.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the checks on backend side. Check for null value for username and show a proper prompt.

Something like this:

```
 if not name://i.e., if null
     messagebox.showwarning('Warning', 'Please insert a valid username')
 else:
     //insert to database
```

Answer (score 0):

just to check 2 cases in python and then try to execute sql query.

```
name = namefield.get() 
if not name or len(name) > 20:
    print('Please insert a valid username')
else:
    try:
        c.execute('''INSERT INTO myuser (username) VALUES (%s)''', (name,))
    except psycopg2.IntegrityError:
        conn.rollback()
    else:
        conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in many ways, the best I think is to either check for the validity of the fields:

```
if name == None or len(name)>20:
   messagebox.showwarning('Warning', 'Invalid username')
```

Or you can achieve the on the DB side, by creating specific triggers that raises a particular exception then call the query in a try like this:

```
try:
        c.execute('''INSERT INTO myuser (username)
    VALUES (%s)''', (name,)
    )

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        messagebox.showwarning('Warning', Error)

        return
```

I used the function show warning since you talked about warnings but I would suggest you to try with the show error too